# definition of a "right makes a wrong"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics, word-play

Sir Paul Maccartney's Drangfly lyric has a passage like:

"How did two rights make a wrong?"

source: "https://genius.com/Paul-mccartney-and-wings-little-lamb-dragonfly-lyrics"

wha does that means "to make a wrong"?

also I belive this next example goes in same direction:

"Admitting to Wrongs Makes a Right"

"Wrongs Makes a Right"???

Comment: Look up the common expression, "two wrongs don't make a right". McCartney is playing on this expression by reversing some words.

Comment: @gotube: How come I get ticked off for answering in comments, but you don't?

Comment: @gotube  This could be the basis of a full answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I give something answer-like in a comment, it's probably not of high enough quality to be a proper answer. In this case here, it's not even an answer. I'm directing the OP to where they can find the answer because this question is answerable with a little research.

Comment: @gotube:  It was a rhetorical question! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ahh!! Too bad there's no "rhetorical question" emoji

Comment: @gotube: I added the "wordplay" tag. We should probably use that tag more often here - especially relevant when that tag alone "explains" much, but the OP doesn't get the reference because it's not in his native tongue.

Answer (score 1):

There is an English expression "Two wrongs don't make a right". It means that you should not retaliate.  If someone does something bad to you (ie if someone wrongs you) and you do something bad to them to retaliate, then this is still wrong and bad.

The familiar expression uses the meaning of make used in arithmetic: "Two and two makes four".

McCartney is playing with this expression poetically. He is rhetorically asking "If I did something good to you, and you did something good to me, why is that wrong?"  The full lyrical analysis is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: The familiar expression uses the meaning of _make_ used in arithmetic: "Two and two makes four".

Comment: That is a good observation, and I've incorporated it, thanks.